# Knowing if a function belong to an Lp space

Tags: lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

[Link to problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYamA.png)

Function: $f = -3\cdot 1_{[-2,-1]}+2\cdot1_{[3,+\infty)}$ (It is a step function)

If figured out that the integral wrt. the Lebesgue measure is equal to \infty as

$f= -3\cdot(2)+2\cdot(\infty)=\infty$

I need to figure out if the function $f$ belongs to any Lp space, for $p>1$. I know that it does not belong in any Lp space for $p<\infty$. But I am not sure if it belongs to the space for $p = \infty$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and [How to ask a good question ?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Answer (score 1):

Your integral is wrong, it should rather be
$$\int_{\mathbb R} f\,\mathrm d \lambda =-3+2\cdot \infty =\infty .$$

Moreover, $$|f|=3\boldsymbol 1_{[-2,-1]}+2\boldsymbol 1_{[3,\infty )}\geq \boldsymbol 1_{[3,\infty )}.$$

Therefore $$|f|^p\geq \boldsymbol 1_{[3,\infty )}\notin L^p(\mathbb R),$$
for all $p\geq 1$.