# How to show that a given function doesn't belong to some $L^p$ space?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I start by saying that my background on classical $L^p$ spaces and Lebesgue integration **is not** strong. There is mainly only one result that I keep in mind about Lebesgue integration and that is: if the Riemann integral exists, then the Lebesgue integral coincides with the Riemann one. There is certainly one question that comes up from this, which is: what happens when the Riemann integral is infinite? On the other hand, how can one evaluate a Lebesgue integral as infinite? All of this question came up from a specific question, which I present below:

**Question.** Show that the function $f(x) = \frac{5}{6} x^{-2/5}$ is not in $L^3 ( \, ]0,1[ \, ).$

In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4510216/knowing-if-a-function-belong-to-an-lp-space), for example, the answerer compares the function they're studying with a characteristic function (for which we know how to compute Lebesgue integrals explicity, since we just need to know the measure of the set in question). I haven't seen any other way of showing that a given Lebesgue integral is infinite and I don't think this same procedure can be applied to my specific question.

**My work thus far.** Obviously, I wish to prove that

$$ \int_0^1 |f(x)|^3 dx = +\infty. $$

It is clear that this happens if we are talking about Riemann integrals, but surely that's not enough to reach anywhere. So, I would like to ask for help /tips about on how to procede in this kind of scenarios.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Surely the problem with integrability lies at the origin, $0$. Hence, consider the integral from $\varepsilon$ to $1$ for some $\varepsilon > 0$. Then $f$ is surely Riemann integrable, and the Riemann integral coincides with the Lebesgue integral. See what happens when you let $\varepsilon\rightarrow 0$ and what it tells you about Lebesgue integrability.

Comment: You can actually evaluate this improper integral directly, right? The integrand is positive and you can calculate its antiderivative immediately. It *is* improper, so you will have to consider $\lim\limits_{h\to 0+}\int\limits_h^1\cdots$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A general way to check if a nonnegative function $f$ is in $L^p$ is to check its level sets. It's a theorem that a nonnegative function $f\in L^p$ if and only if
$$
\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}2^{np}|\underbrace{\{x:2^n < f(x)\le 2^{n+1}\}}_{\equiv E_n}| < \infty.
$$
The rationale is that $f(x)^p \approx (2^n)^p$ exactly when $x\in \{2^n<f\le 2^{n+1}\}$, and these level sets are disjoint, so the Lebesgue integral $\int f^p \approx \sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}2^{np}|E_n|$ by the Monotone Convergence Theorem. (I am using $|E|$ to represent the Lebesgue measure of $E$.)

Coming to the example you asked about, $f(x) = x^{-2/5}$, so the level set
$$
E_n = \{x\in (0,1]:2^n < f(x)\le 2^{n+1}\}
$$
is an interval of length (Lebesgue measure) $\approx 2^{-\frac{5n}{2}}$ whenever $n \ge 0$, and they are empty when $n < 0$. Therefore, we just have to check the convergence/divergence of
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{3n}2^{-5n/2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{n/2},
$$
which diverges to $+\infty$. Hence $f\notin L^3((0,1])$. Based on this computation and the level sets criterion, this particular $f\in L^p$ if and only if $p < 5/2$.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I understood most of the answer but I have a few questions: $1)$ How did you come up with the interval of length $2^{-\frac{5n}{2}}$ for $n \geqslant 0$ ? And $2)$ Do you have any book reference for this theorem?

Comment: @xyz: You can calculate exactly which half-open interval $E_n$ is using the equation for $f(x)$ and the defining relation for $E_n$. It's something like $E_n = \{x\in(0,1]:2^n<x^{-2/5}\le 2^{n+1}\}=[2^{-\frac{5(n+1)}{2}},2^{-\frac{5n}{2}})$. You can calculate the length of that interval as the right endpoint minus the left endpoint. My favorite reference is Stein & Shakarchi's volume 3 "Real Analysis." I think any textbook on Lebesgue integration should include this theorem, though. And like I said it is an immediate corollary of the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: I was able to reach the interval $[2^{-\frac{5(n+1)}{2}}, 2^{-\frac{5n}{2}})$ before posting up the comment, what I didn't understand is why is this length equal to the upper bound. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: @xyz: It looks like the length is exactly $2^{-\frac{5n}{2}}(1-2^{-5/2})$, which is $\approx 2^{-5n/2}$. I am using the notation $A \approx B$ to mean $A$ and $B$ agree up to universal multiplicative factors.